# how to get FindControl Method in desktop application in C#

Tags: c#

Hii

Iam not able to find the FindControl Method.this is the event "_CellEndEdit (object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)" in which Iam trying to access findControl....but I dont see that method...please tell me how can I access this method...

Comment: Please post some code (EDIT: or at least describe what you're trying to achieve...).

Comment: I want to validate the textboxes in the datagrid....I want to get the value of cell using findcontrol and then validate that value to check if the input text is in the required format.....

Answer (score 0):

I believe `FindControl` is a method on the `Control` class in the `System.Web.UI` namespace.  In WinForms, you don't require this.

What control are you trying to find?  Is it a grid editing control?

Will you use this control to get the cell value?

**Update:** the cell value is presented on the cell itself, there is no need to find the control underling the cell.  The event arguments either contain the cell itself, the value itself, or the `RowIndex` and `ColumnIndex`.  Using the latter, you can get the cell from the grid and review its `.Value` property:

```
DataGridViewCell c = grid[colIndex, rowIndex];
```

Note also there is a `CellValidating` cancellable event on the grid that sounds more suitable to your needs.

Comment: I want to find the textboxes which are present in the datagrid....yes I want to get the cell value so that I can validate if the input data is in date format....but only if I get FindControl :( is there any namespace which Iam missing?

Comment: CellValidating is giving me the value of first row & first column of the datagrid....is there any way by which I can get the value of the current cell being edited....

Comment: I'am using rowindex and column index to get the value...can you also help me in checking if the input string is a valid datetime...
if (dgvBusWiseInfo.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["TripStartTime1"].ValueType == typeof(DateTime)) this is the code I've written, but it returns false even when I enter the right input...thanks

Comment: Really that should be another question, but use `DateTime.TryParse`, this will return false if it couldn't parse your date.  Note this doesn't take into account DateTime locales.  Also, it won't be a `typeof DateTime`, it will be a string that you convert to a DateTime.

Comment: Ive successfully validated the textbox...there was no need of Find Control...thanks you right suggestion at the right time :)

Comment: Adam I tried to mark your answer as accepted....but I couldnt find any such option...may be because I was unregistered....I've registered to this account now and will make it a point to mark...

Answer (score 0):

The `FindControl` method is only available for instances of the `Control` class and its descendants. So you could call it on the form like

```
this.FindControl(...);
```

**EDIT**
As for your comment:

1. The `_CellEndEdit` event is the wrong place to do such validation. You'd usually implement the `_CellValidating` event.
2. If you *must* use `_CellEndEdit` to validate the inputs, you can try to use the `EditingControl` property of the `DataGridView`. This should return the current editing control for the cell if the cell is in edit mode. However, it may be that the `_CellEndEdit` event is called *after* the edit control is already destroyed.
3. The `DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs` object passed to `_CellEndEdit` allows you to get the value that was entered and set the `Cancel` property (maybe along with a cell error), so that the changes are cancelled.

Comment: Assuming the OP is using WinForms, `System.Windows.Forms.Control` doesn't have a `FindControl` method.  WPF, I'm not sure about.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Control.ControlCollection.Find method.

i.e:

```
this.Controls.Find()
```